# What are the files/details that need to copied when I change my PC

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, desktop-computer, copy-paste, migration

I am a PHP developer & I am using a desktop PC which I bought 3 years back. I do all my development work in this desktop PC.

Couple of days back, I bought a brand new PC with higher configuration & I want to move all the required details from my old PC to new PC. I am not sure what are the details to be copied from my old pc to new pc.

I already copied/moved the below to the new PC

- Exported browser bookmarks from old PC & Imported it into new PC
- Exported FTP details from old PC & Imported it into new PC.
- Copied project source code & DB from WAMP in old PC to new PC.
- Moved email PST data file from old PC to new PC
- Copied files from downloads folder in old PC to new PC.
- Installed required software's as a developer

I though FTP & browser bookmarks are important.

Am I missing something important that I still need to copy from old PC to new PC?. I tried to search in stackexchange websites to know if someone already got an answer but I didn't find any.

Very much appreciate your help!

Comment: What OS are you transferring FROM and TO?

Comment: @CharlieRB, it was windows 7 in my old pc & windows 8.1 in my new pc

Comment: Any reason you are not using Windows Easy Transfer?

Comment: I am not sure if it moves FTP details, browser bookmarks and other similar information.